# Generating Scala models from Swagger spec

Tags: scala, vert.x, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to build a Vert.X app using Scala, and generating the routes using an OpenAPI 3 spec through the `OpenAPI3RouterFactory`.
I need to generate the models described in my spec as Scala classes.
Is there any simple and straightforward way to accomplish this?

I'm using SBT to build my app, and I've already tried some *sbt codegen plugins* for Swagger, but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vertx-web-api-contract, Router and validation handlers are generated at runtime, so you don't need to generate the routes. You can just start using the Router factory and mount the handlers you want as if it would be a Vert.x Web Router. If you want to bootstrap a new project there is a community tool called [vertx-starter](https://github.com/pmlopes/vertx-starter), but there is no Scala support now

Talking about the models, what you can do is organize your OpenAPI specification in different files, putting all data model definitions under a specific directory like `spec/models` (You can find a good guide [here](https://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-8-splitting-specification-file/)). Then you can configure [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) ([sbt plugin](https://index.scala-lang.org/catap/sbt-jsonschema2pojo/sbt-jsonschema2pojo/0.3?target=_2.10_0.13)) to generate a Scala case class for each schema inside that directory. Then, if you want to repack the spec in a single file, you can configure tools like [swagger-cli](https://github.com/APIDevTools/swagger-cli) to run during the compilation and pack the spec back in a single file

Comment: Thanks, that sbt plugin was really helpful. I managed to succeed using the OpenAPI Generator with Docker, but with that sbt plugin, I might be able to generate the models on compile.